# Sabrent 7-port USB powered hub somehow doesn’t have enough power?

Tags: power, usb-3, usb-hub

System Specs:

- i5 13600k
- GTX 4080
- 32GB DDR5 RAM
- 2TB M.2 NVME
- 1000w PSU
- Windows 11 (updated to latest 23H2 (KB5034204) )

I have bought [this Sabrent powered USB hub](https://sabrent.com/products/hb-b7c3) from Amazon, twice now.

The first one arrived and I plugged it into my computer and into the wall and noticed that a notification pops up on my computer, stating that:

> "There is not enough power on the usb"
> The hub does not have enough power to support the composite device.

(X56 Throttle Quadrant - Device works, and works when plugged directly into the PC) This happens on the top 3 ports of the hub, however the last 4 work as intended, I initially put this down to faulty device so ordered another one in replacement and that does the exact same thing, in the exact same environment.  I have taken every USB device out of the PC bar the hub and same result.

It worked a few times, but always resulted in it failing back to the USB Not enough power. I have tried both hubs in an alternate PC and both work on that with no issues.  his PC is around 12 months old when I built it, and I'm tearing my hair out at what could be causing this. I have two 4 port Sabrent daisy chained into a port without issue, and they are running on the PC power not mains, so I am at a loss.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Are you using a different cable to connect it to the PC vs. Other PC?

Comment: Same cable that came with the hub. Only thing that changed between PC's was the device that was plugged in.

Comment: Good.  It's not the cord then, which I've seen sooo many times when going port types to hubs to different devices, with chaining and all that fun.  Sometimes that one old cord will be the weakest link.

Answer (score 0):

Sabrent has a firmware update available that will fix the issue.
Go to https://sabrent.com/pages/downloads and enter the model number of your hub to find the files for it. There is a guide inside with images to get you through the process.

NOTE: Antivirus software may flag the zip file itself or a file named rhc.exe once it is extracted. Sabrent has stated that it is a false positive, but to be safe rather than running that file you can run ._cache_RHC.exe in the same folder. Simply use a Run prompt to point to it or uncheck "Hide protected operating system files" in the file explorer properties menu. Be sure to re-enable it afterwards.